# Execute specific code based on input type

Tags: dart

I need a function that accepts all subclasses of a parent class, this function will check the type of the argument it received and then it will do some specific operation on it, something like this:

```dart
class Animal {
  String sound;
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  String sound = 'Meow';
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  final String sound = 'Roof';
  final String somePropertyOnlyDogHave = 'Best friend';
}

void foo<T extends Animal>(T animal) {
  print(T.runtimeType);
  switch(T) {
    case Cat:
      print(animal.sound);
      break;
    case Dog:
      print(animal.sound);
      print(animal.somePropertyOnlyDogHave);
      break;
    default:
      print('No match');
  }
}
```

The code above doesn't compile, because `somePropertyOnlyDogHave` is not defined on the parent class.
How can achieve this functionality without having to define `somePropertyOnlyDogHave` on the parent class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a *switch/case*, consider using *if/else* with `is` operator:

```
void foo<T extends Animal>(T animal) {
  print(T.runtimeType);
  if (animal is Cat) {
    print(animal.sound);
  } else if (animal is Dog) {
    print(animal.sound);
    print(animal.somePropertyOnlyDogHave);
  } else {
    print('No match');
  }
}
```

Using this syntax, Dart infers `animal` as `Dog` within the scope of the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

you can cast the `animal` to type dog inside the `Dog` case, like this:

```
    case Dog:
      Dog dog = animal;
      print(dog.sound);
      print(dog.somePropertyOnlyDogHave);
      break;
```

Comment: Note that the switch-case won't work with `Dog` subclasses.

Comment: yeah. @RémiRousselet is correct. his answer is better.